# Solution to stack laptops safely

Tags: laptop, storage, physical-wear

Not sure I'm in the right place here because what I'm looking for I suppose can be classed as hardware, but it's more to do with tidying desk space I guess.

Anyway, what I'm looking for a solution that will enable me to stack laptops on top of each other on my desk without damaging them. I own three laptops and regularly get given laptops to fix so a lot of the time I don't have enough desk space for all of them and so have to resort to stacking them on top of each. I don't like doing this for several reason, not least because its one of the easiest ways to damage laptops, but what happens when I want to use the laptop at the bottom...

To my surprise I cannot find anything out there that already exists to solve this problem (I can't be the only one?). The closest thing I have come up with is stackable A3 letter trays but they are £15+ each, so I'm going to end up spending at least nearly £100, which seems a lot. So, does anyone here know of any solutions?

I'm in the UK by the way.

Comment: This will most likely be closed as off-topic. Still it is a good question. Quick google search using "Latpop storage shelf" and "laptop storage rack" shows that there are producst on the market but they are fairly expensive. You might want to DIY. Its easier than you think!

Comment: I feared that it might be closed to be honest - it may be more suited to a traditional forum rather than a Q&A website, but I thought it would still be worth a shot as the only products I can find are expensive and overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Buy some wide shelf stock at the local home improvement store, and a few bricks.  I'm not familiar with lumber (timber) prices in UK, but this shouldn't cost as much as twenty UKP for the whole stack -- and it's expandable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the route that I have ended up going down in the end. It's not wood and bricks, but what I've ordered is actually designed for storing shoes and clothes. I paid £50 for 26 metal sheets that are just about the right size, but I'll use less than half to build the laptop rack so it is actually a good deal - if it works... I'll post here if it does. It's still not a perfect solution even if it does work though